# Facebook upload fail error when sharing image through android app

Tags: android, facebook, share

Here is what I am trying to do!

I am taking screenshot and saving it in my phone and then picking up the same uri and uploading it on facebook via facebook integration for share.

My code is not working, I am able to open facebook share dialog and it shows my screenshot there. But when i press post button, a toast is displayed by facebook saying "your photo will be uploaded. please check progress in notification bar."

And in notification bar, I get a message that "facebook upload failed. Your photo couldn't be uploaded."

This is my code

```
  private static Bitmap takeScreenShot(Activity activity) {

 View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();

        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
        Rect frame = new Rect();
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
        int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
        int width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int height = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getHeight();

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height
                - statusBarHeight);
        view.destroyDrawingCache();
        Log.e("Screenshot", "taken successfully");
        return b;

    }

    public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            File pictureStorage = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File LuckPercentage = new File(pictureStorage, "Luck Percentage");
            if (!LuckPercentage.exists())
                LuckPercentage.mkdirs();




            File imagePath = new File(LuckPercentage
                    + "/screenshot-" + shot + ".png");
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                Log.e("Screenshot", "saved successfully");

                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            openScreenshot(imagePath);
        }


    }
    private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        Log.e("path", ""+uri);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        //startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Then, I am calling a dialog box where i want to show my screenshot and facebook share button.

```
 public void open() {

 dialog = new Dialog(context);

  // super(context,R.style.Theme_Dialog_Translucent);

  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.final_calculation);


   dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.Theme_Dialog_Translucent;

   screen = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

 final ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.fb_share_button);


        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setImageUrl(uri).build();
         content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();
        shareButton.setShareContent(content);



        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {






            shareDialog.show(content);
        }
    }
});

        dialog.show();
    }
```

This is what i have added to manifest

```
<manifest>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application>
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id" />

 <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
            android:value="@string/app_name" />

 <provider

  android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"


android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider707840309410113"
            android:exported="true" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: And what response do you get in your android error logs?

Comment: This is what i am getting in warn section. though i have added AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this); in onCreate method.

W/com.facebook.appevents.internal.ActivityLifecycleTracker: Unexpected activity pause without a matching activity resume. Logging data may be incorrect. Make sure you call activateApp from your Application's onCreate method

Comment: i have also tried AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this); in onResume() method. But still i am unable to upload image.

Comment: also this is the output i am getting form FacebookCallback<Share.Result>() method's onSuccess method
 
E/fb success: com.facebook.share.Sharer$Result@fc9984a

Answer (score 0):

I get same error maybe.

I resolve it by add meta-data in AndroidManifest.xml as blow:

`<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
        android:value="{Display name in Facebook API Base Setting}" />`

com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName should not be package name. It actually represent display name in API SETTING.

You may find Facebook API Setting page [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)

Comment: thanks allen :) 
but my issue was in the spelling of the name of app that i have registered on Fb with what I am building in android studio.
I have resolved my issue.